# What documents are needed to establish a family relationship for an aunt and uncle to obtain a tourist visa to the USA?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, international-travel

My husband is planning to invite my aunt and uncle to visit us in the USA for sightseeing purposes. It is my mom's sister and her husband. What documents need to be submitted in order to establish our relationship for the tourist visa application?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html), after they complete the online visa application process and schedule an interview, here’s what to consider:

> **Additional Documentation May Be Required**
>
> Review the instructions for how to apply for a visa on the website of the [U.S. Embassy or Consulate](https://www.usembassy.gov/india/) where you will apply. Additional documents may be requested to establish if you are qualified. For example, additional requested documents may include evidence of:
>
> - The purpose of your trip,
> - Your intent to depart the United States after your trip, and/or
> - Your ability to pay all costs of the trip.
>
> Evidence of your employment and/or your family ties may be sufficient to show the purpose of your trip and your intent to return to your home country. If you cannot cover all the costs for your trip, you may show evidence that another person will cover some or all costs for your trip.
>
> **Note**: Visa applicants must qualify on the basis of the applicant's residence and ties abroad, rather than assurances from U.S. family and friends. A letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support is not needed to apply for a visitor visa. If you choose to bring a letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support to your interview, please remember it is not one of the factors used in determining whether to issue or deny the visa.

Proof of relationship may not be necessary but, should it be, birth certificates may do it: your aunt’s, your mother’s, and yours.